# django primary key auto assigning available id from least value

Tags: django, django-forms, django-custom-field

In django project primary key are assigned automatically.
In my model I have some model object with id (=5,6).
id (= 1,2,3,4,) is deleted from the DB.
Now when I create new object model,django assigning id with the value 7.
But I want this to assign in a order like  1,2,3,4 and 7 and so.
How can I implement this?

I've tried to create a complete different id field with custom logic to assign the available id first,but I was expecting a django built-in function.

Comment: Please *don't*. This has been asked multiple times, but really would only result in a huge amount of trouble.

Comment: One for example would be that a person that bookmarks a page with one primary key, eventually can find the page be replaced with some other object, instead of an expected 404.

Comment: You should see primary keys as "black box" tokens, where the fact that these are integers is merely an "implementation detail". It is just something to uniquely describe an object.